# Woocommerce - Forget Shipping Address Per Order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am testing orders on my drop shipping website which uses Woocommerce and I'm struggling to work out how to force the Shipping Address per each check out / individual order to be blank each time.

Currently it is remembering the shipping address of the last order made by that particular user, however my customers will be sending orders to their own customers at different addresses each order they make.

Ideally for convenience, every time they check out with an order in their basket it will show their billing address saved as standard (as per their profile) however it will reset the shipping address to be completely blank, so they can fill it in each time instead of replacing/deleting the previous order details.

I have searched for a way to do this but unfortunately cannot find anything at all! Would anyone be kind enough to help me understand how to force a blank shipping address for every individual order that one user will make?

I really, really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customise woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-shipping.php template file by copying to your theme you will find this line in code

```
woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) );
```

replace it with

```
woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field );
```